# Fail2Ban v0.9 On Fedora 20 "[Errno 24] Too many open files" error

Tags: fedora20, fail2ban

After successfully installing fail2ban on Fedora 20 server (Running On Digital Ocean) using [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fail2ban_with_FirewallD) guide, I checked the fail2ban logs only to find that there were multiple "[Errno 24] Too many open files" errors.

I googled around and realized that I need to increase the number of file descriptors for fail2ban (which currently stands at 1024), but couldn't find a working solution.

How can I increase the number of file descriptors for fail2ban, or is there any other workaround under this environment?

Answer (score 3):

```
# mkdir --parents /etc/systemd/system/fail2ban.service.d
# cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/fail2ban.service.d/limits.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=2048
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: This actually worked.  Thanks.  Please mark as correct answer.